# Limiting the posts on the homepage to one taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy

I've currently got this code on my homepage to display one random post from the Work section on my website - this is a custom post type utilising taxonomies - not blog posts:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=work&posts_per_page=1&orderby=rand'); ?>
```

I want the items to be randomised so that a different one displays each time and I only want to display one item. However I want to know if it's possible to limit it to just one taxonomy rather than all 5 that I have set up. I'd like to just show the work items listed within 'Artists'

Is this possible?

----EDIT------------

I've tried:

```
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'work' => 'artists', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'posts_per_page' => '1' ) ); ?>
```

but this doesn't work - it brings back a link top 'home' instead. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more details about your taxonomy schema, giving a precise answer will be difficult. However, [`query_posts()` can be filtered by taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters), so you should easily be able to do what you need.

Comment: I've created a cutom post type called work and within this created 5 taxonomies - one of which is 'artists'. I would like to display 1 random artists taxonomy on the homepage for each visit. How would I adjust my code to do this as I've tried a few things from the link you've given and nothing works.